# Disable (button) link with data-rel="back" in AngularJS and jQuery Mobile

Tags: html, angularjs, jquery-mobile

I have a back button in an app build with AngularJS and jQuery Mobile with the following problem.

Depending on the state of a property I want to set the button to disabled, but ng-disabled which I could bind to a property only works with buttons, as far as I know. On the other hand, data-rel="back" only works with links.

Basically the code looks like that, pretty straight-forward.

```
<a href="" data-role="button" data-rel="back">Back</a>
```

A property called isSubmitting is set when another button is clicked and when that happens the back button should be changed to disabled.

Is there an easy solution to this? I've found a couple of workarounds, but they all seem pretty bloated and complicated for a rather simple problem.

Comment: Easiest way to disable an anchor `$("[data-rel=back]").addClass("ui-disabled");`

Comment: http://www.gajotres.net/enable-disable-jquery-mobile-button/

Comment: @Gajotres too many issues aren't explained in documentations. Your blog is a good reference, great job.

Comment: Omar, thanks. That was the hint I needed to solve my problem. (At least I hope so.)